# Base64 URL encoding fail

Tags: python, base64

I have a little program here which try to generate a specific hash value for a website (Path of Exile Passive Tree).

Here is my code:

```
####### ByteEncoder.py (This is a python convert from the official js code )

class ByteEncoder:
  def __init__(self):
    self.dataString = ""

  def intToBytes(self, t, n=4):
    t = int(t)

    i = [None] * n
    s = n - 1
    while True:
      i[s] = 255 & t
      t = t>>8
      s -= 1
      if s < 0:
        break

    return i

  def appendInt(self, t, n):
    i = self.intToBytes(t,n)
    for r in range(0, n):
      self.dataString += chr(i[r])

  def appendInt8(self, t):
    self.appendInt(t, 1)

  def appendInt16(self, t):
    self.appendInt(t, 2)

  def getDataString(self):
    return self.dataString

##### main.py

hashes = [465, 45035]

encoder = ByteEncoder()

encoder.appendInt(4,4) # Tree Version
encoder.appendInt8(2) # Class ID
encoder.appendInt8(0) # Ascendency class
encoder.appendInt8(1) # Fullscreen

for h in hashes:
  encoder.appendInt16(h)

d = str(base64.b64encode(bytes(encoder.getDataString(),encoding='utf8')))

d = d.replace("+", "-").replace("/", "_")

print(d)
```

I get the Hash AAAABAIAAQHDkcKvw6s= but i should get AAAABAIAAQHRr-s=

Can someone tell me why?

If you wanna test this

What i want:
https://www.pathofexile.com/fullscreen-passive-skill-tree/3.6.6/AAAABAIAAQHRr-s=

What i get:
https://www.pathofexile.com/fullscreen-passive-skill-tree/3.6.6/AAAABAIAAQHDkcKvw6s=

**Here is the Anwser from the comment of [Victor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56430004/base64-url-encoding-fail/56430642#comment99464961_56430642)**. 
Simply use `base64.urlsafe_b64encode()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are treating your text string as if it where bytes, and then encoding it with `utf-8`, which is a multi-byte encoding.

If you need a "transparent" text-to-bytes encoding, use "latin-1".
However, in this code, you should not have been using a text-string ("str") to startwith. It will also simplify things in that you can concatenate the integers directly into your data, instead of converting byte by byte:

```
...
class ByteEncoder:
  def __init__(self):
    self.data = bytes()

  ...

  def appendInt(self, t, n):
    i = self.intToBytes(t,n)
    self.data += i

...
# Also,in Python, there is no sense in writting a  "getter" to
# just return an attribute as it is - no need for an equivalent
# of your `.getDataString` method:

d = str(base64.b64encode(encoder.data))
```

Comment: By the way, I think it should be noted that Python has the built-in function `base64.urlsafe_b64encode()`, so there is no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: so the line self.data += i results in an "can't concat list to bytes"-error. also with a for loop above it i get "can't concat int to bytes". The cool thing is the comment from Victor did the trick! Thanks man